# LiveReload: CSS usually not being updated (Chrome)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, livereload

I've got a LiveReload setup where reloading seems to be working fine, but whatever changes I make to the CSS it is usually not be applied before I perform a page refresh.

What I am observing:

1. Browser connects to server: I see "Browser connected." in the logs)
2. Whenever I make a change to a file I can see LiveReload reacting: I see "Browser reloading /path/to/file" in the log.
3. Whenever the file is an HTML file, the browser completely reloads the page.
4. Whenever the file is a CSS file I can see the file being reloaded, both indicated by the server logs and Chrome's developer tools, but nothing happens to the layout. I've included a screenshot of the results of two edits to my css file: [image]
5. Now and then the browser is actually updated, but I have not been able to see a pattern as to when this happens.

Anyone know what might be up here?

---

I'm not sure that it is relevant since the actual reloading is working here, but my setup consists of guard-livereload 2.1.1 and rack-livereload 0.3.15 (to avoid having to use the browser plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I notice that the file being load were not the file that I was actually editing. In my this was happening when I had two scss files with the same name.

i.e:

- partial/file.scss
- module/file.scss

if you make modification in modale/file.scss, it may relaod the compiled version of partial/file.scss

Comment: A bit late for me to get back on this one, but I did not have multiple files with the same name.